# Getting actual Field name and Value : Simplified ver

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Let say I have 3 tables: Standard_Code and Report and Transactions.

> **Standard_Code** table field name: **Code**
>
> Values are: Opening_Balance, Ending_Balance, Actual_Remaining_Balance
>
> **Report** table field names: Opening_Balance, Ending_Balance, Actual_Remaining_Balance

You might think why would I do this kind of duplicates? Well, technically they are different since the 'Standard_Code' table has row values but in my 'Report' they are columns and they are fixed and can't be changed.

> $sql = "Select t.code, t.amount From Transactions t Inner Join Standard_Code sc on
>   t.code = sc.code";
>
> $result = mysql_query($sql);
>
> while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
>
> ```
>     foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
>         echo $col." = ".$val."<br />";        
> }
> ```
>
> sqlQuery = "Update Report Set '" . **fieldname** . "' = " . **value** ;
>
> ```
> }
> ```

Supposedly, during the while or foreach loop how to do this query to update the Report table:

**fieldname** : `Code` value from Standard_Code table *(the value here are the Actual Field names of the Report table)*

**value** : From Transactions table : `Amount`

both something I don't know how to work base on my requirement.

**My reason:** I have special requirements that deals with the report specially on value placement/ formatting etc.. in short the report is complicated that is why I created a custom Report table so I can easily get the report data to format.

Comment: Where the `$result` variable comes from and what is its content

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe added more details about $result

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "Select t.code, t.amount From Transactions t Inner Join Standard_Code sc on t.code = sc.code";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$q = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $q[] = $row['code'].' = '.$row['amount'];    
}
// UPDATE report SET Opening_Balance = 2, Ending_Balance = 2, Actual_Remaining_Balance = 2
mysql_query('UPDATE Report SET '.join(', ', $q));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understand your case as you want to update the total sum of each type of `code` when you loop through your transaction. This is my code (we should not you the `mysql_` api any more, I use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) instead)

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $db->prepare("Select t.code, t.amount From Transactions t Inner Join Standard_Code sc on t.code = sc.code");
if ($stmt->exectute())
{
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $stmt = "Update Report Set `" . $row['code'] . "` = `" . $row['code'] . "` + :val";   
        $stmt->bindValue(":val", $row['amount']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

In this case, your `report` table will only have **one** row. You can also modify this code to **INSERT** new row instead of **UPDATE** the old record. However, you need an additional primary key column if using this approach.